# Combine 2 rows into 1

Tags: r

In a data frame is it possible to combine rows into 1 row as per group. For example,

```
df
A         B        C
xyz   C1 : 12     23
xyz   C2 : 13     23
abc   C1 : 12     43
abc   C2 : 34     43
abc   C3 : 43     43
```

Expected output. Now we have only 2 rows. In the second column the rows are combined. But placed in the next line only

```
df1
A         B        C

xyz   C1 : 12     23
      C2 : 13   
  
      C1 : 12     
abc   C2 : 34     43
      C3 : 43
```

Comment: I need to represent this in a shiny application. For example, ````C1 : 12 /n C2 : 13````(next line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking to display the data in this way, but not do anything else with it, you could use flextable (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56327225/12957340)):

```
library(tidyverse)
#install.packages("flextable")
library(flextable)

df <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                 A = c("xyz", "xyz", "abc", "abc", "abc"),
                 B = c("C1 : 12", "C2 : 13", "C1 : 12", "C2 : 34", "C3 : 43"),
                 C = c(23L, 23L, 43L, 43L, 43L))

flextable(df) %>%
  theme_box() %>% 
  merge_v(j = ~A)
```

[image: example_1.png]